# Removing a certain section of a path

Tags: c#-4.0

I've got a number of paths like in memory (contained in an ArrayList):

> C:\Program Files\Product\file.xml

What I want to do is remove the 'C:\Program Files\' from the path, so that just 'Product\file.xml'. I know I could do this simply by replacing the 'C:\Program Files\' with '', but the problem comes when I have paths from a localized environment, e.g. German where the path becomes:

> C:\Programme\Product\file.xml

Any suggestions on how to do this?

In plain English, I want to remove everything before and including the second '\'.

Thanks.

Comment: Why the -1, I think my explanation/question is pretty clear???

Comment: I didnt -1 your question. By the way, did you follow my suggestion above?

Comment: I used Gabe's solution below, I've always been quite fearful of using REGEX ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take everything after the second backslash, use this:

```
path.Substring(path.IndexOf('\\', path.IndexOf('\\') + 1) + 1)
```

If all you want to do is take everything after the second-to-last backslash, use this:

```
path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('\\', path.LastIndexOf('\\') - 1) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have visual studio on this machine, so I can't verify, but it should be something along these lines:

```
myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf('\\', myString.IndexOf('\\')))
```

You might need to add a "+ 1" after that second IndexOf call to get it to search at the right place, though